# How can I a make model acts_as_authentic that doesn't have the persistence_token field or related functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I would like to use only the `perishable_token` feature from authlogic on this model and nothing else. Here's what I've tried so far that's failed:

```
class EmailInvite < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.disable_perishable_token_maintenance = true
    c.maintain_sessions = false
  end
end
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just using `Authlogic::Random.friendly_token` to generate the token and then did everything else outside of authlogic:

```
class EmailInviteObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

    def after_create(email_invite)
      email_invite.perishable_token = Authlogic::Random.friendly_token
      email_invite.save
    end

end
```